Man mistaken for cop by drug dealers
The main character is getting ready to start a job with the FBI or CIA or something and in the beginning he has a black crown vic, an old police cruiser, and they pull up by drug dealers who think they are cops and run, throwing their dope and money.  So they pull up and get the dealers stuff and drive off.
I'm thinking the guy played in Species but I can't find his picture in the cast list. -- EDIT: NO HE WAS NOT ON SPECIES -- EDIT AGAIN -- I'm not entirely sure, it might have been the dude who was an astronaut and got infected with the Species and blew his head off and it grew back.
He had a bad drinking problem and became really violent and was prone to "go off the handle" for no real reason.

Any more detail - when did you see this even?

It is probably an early 90's maybe late 90's movie.  I can't remember, it was really good though.  The guy had an affair with a woman in Mexico also.  He kind of went a little crazy, robbing dealers and such.  And then in one scene he held his gun to the side of his friends head inside the car.

Could it be Harsh Times (2005)?
Ford Crown Victoria Police Interceptor
From Wikipedia:

Jim Davis (Christian Bale) is a former U.S. Army Ranger who suffers
  from Post Traumatic Stress Disorder (PTSD).
Jim has a Mexican girlfriend, Marta (Tammy Trull), whom he is
  determined to marry, and bring into the United States to start a life
  together. 
With this in mind, Jim returns to Los Angeles, California.
In Los Angeles, 
    Jim meets up with his best friend Mike Alonzo (Freddy
  Rodriguez). Mike's longtime girlfriend, Sylvia (Eva Longoria), a young attorney, is "on the warpath" over his failure to get a job (his previous job
  was outsourced) and she encourages Jim to help Mike hand out resumes.
After being denied a position in the Los Angeles Police Department for
  failing the psychological profile, Jim gets drunk with Mike, 
  forgetting all about the resumes.
The two go to visit Jim's ex-girlfriend, but when her current
  boyfriend shows up, a fight ensues in which the boyfriend is backed up
  by a group of friends. 
Jim is able to get the upper hand and when Mike produces a gun, they
  subdue the men and rob them of their possessions, including marijuana
  and a handgun which they later decide to sell. 
They then go to a "paisa" bar to try to sell the gun, but leave after
  their potential buyer is stabbed in the neck and killed. (Mike is horrified, but Jim is strangely excited by witnessing death again)
Jim gets shortlisted for a position with the Department of Homeland
  Security (DHS), and after cheating on a urine test,  it appears that
  he is going to be given a position. Jim manages to pass the urinalysis
  test, but subsequently fails a polygraph test due to a question about
  his drug use.  The only hope left for him is a government agent
  working out of Colombia, who appreciates Jim's ability to "get things
  done";  Jim eventually accepts the position but is warned that he must
  not get married to a foreigner;his security clearance might be
  revoked. Jim is told to report to FLETC in a few days...
Marta reveals that she is pregnant, and Jim responds violently,
  threatening to punch her in the stomach and shoot her in the head; in
  the end, this is a result of Jim's severe PTSD.
Jim reveals that he is transporting 20 kilos of marijuana, much to
  Mike's dismay. When Mike protests,  Jim pulls a gun on him.

...

 While Jim and Mike are escaping in the car, a man from inside the    house steps out and shoots at the car with an Armsel Striker; Jim is hit in the back and the side of his face, and subsequently paralyzed. He urges Mike to "step up" and shoot him, thus ending his suffering. After some hesitation, Mike and Jim say their goodbyes and Mike ends up killing Jim.  


Where is the huge quote block in your answer taken from? Is this from one of the links provided? And why is the last part in code markup? Does it belong into the above quote block or not?

My English is bad.  I can't write a sentence. Quotation from Wikipedia.
I could not do the spoiler option. So I wrote the spoiler part is different.
You can always edit my response.

If you quote external sources, please always make sure to mention the source (preferably with a link) for proper attribution.

Okay, I will do it that way. Thanks!

Could it be Training Day, (2001), with Denzel Washington and Ethan Hawke?  The movie has a scene where Detective Alonzo Harris (Washington) holds a gun to Jake Hoyt's (Hawke's) head:

In Alonzo's car, the officer sees teenage Mara Salvatrucha gang
  members dealing drugs in a park. Alonzo confiscates the drugs and
  tells Jake to take a hit from the marijuana. Jake refuses, but Alonzo
  puts a gun to his head and says Jake's failure to use drugs could get
  him killed by a street dealer.

They do rob dealers as well:

Alonzo takes Jake to Sandman's home in Watts where he uses a fake
  search warrant to steal drug money from the premises. Sandman's wife,
  however, notices and calls out to the nearby armed gang members who
  open fire.


No, it's not training day. Thanks for the close match though!  His partner was latino I think.  His partner had a wife and maybe a baby.
